# Why does my UITableView add another section for me when I insert an entry into an exist section?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I use NSFetchedResultController and CoreData to manage my UITableView, but I have a problem. It has really confused me for two days, and I don't know how to deal with it.

I use two entity(Group, Contact) to store my data, and in my tableview, the contact is separated into Group, it works fine when application launch, but just after I add a contact, which is belong to one of the exist Groups, the tableview add a new section for me. That's not what I want.

I have tried two ways and hope to fix it, but...
the first one, I use the grp relationship of contact entity as my section separater. The result is not what I want. So I change to the second one, I add a new attribute(GName) to group my contacts, I thought maybe it's all because of grp is a relationship, so I use an attribute. It dosen't work neither.

Pleeeease help me. any reply will be appreciate.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell without seeing the code, but when you add a contact and save it do you reload the table view for example calling something like [self.tableView reload]?

Comment: NSFetchedResultsController have the ability to reload data and refresh UITableView automaticlly when some changed have made. That's why I choose it. And I wander if I can use relationship as my group seperator?

Comment: How about setting the sectionNameKeyPath to something like grp.Name, in other words using the attribute of the Group object associated with the Contact object instead of the attribute on the Contact object?